# How to limit/control too-many async calls?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I'm kind of new to Node, but I understand that writing syncronous functions is a bad thing. I locks up the event loop or something... So it's good to write everything asyncronous.

But in some cases, writing everything async could be bad. For example I have a function that makes an API call (to a 3rd party API service) and then I have to write the result to a database. I need to do this a bunch over a short period of time, for example 500 times.

Calling this API 500 times async and then writing to the database 500 times async would be probably ban me from the API service (throttling) and overload my database server.

What is the best way to control or limit something like this? I want to keep things async so it's effecient but I simply cannot take the above approach.

I've researched some [Promise throttling](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-throttle) approaches. Is that the correct way to approach this type of problem? Is there a better more appropriate way to do it?

Comment: Take a look at the `async` npm package - specifically the queue: https://github.com/caolan/async#queue

Comment: You will need to rate limit yourself so you don't over-use the API service.  There are modules on NPM to help you do that or you can simply code your own solutions.  If you're doing it yourself, you will just need to keep counters and time stamps so you can keep track of how many API calls have been made in the last N seconds and probably build a queue of commands waiting to go when a time slot opens up.  The details of how to do it depend a lot on your particulars and what rules you're trying to follow on the API.

Comment: [This is a good JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dukeytoo/02ohnth4/) with some nice patterns for looping async calls and that can be used to limit/throttle the number of requests!

Answer (score 2):

The `async` npm package is wonderful and has several solutions that can be used in this particular situation. One approach is using a `queue` with a set concurrency limit (example taken directly from the [`async` README](https://github.com/caolan/async#queue)):

```
// create a queue object with concurrency 2
var q = async.queue(function (task, callback) {
    console.log('hello ' + task.name);
    callback();
}, 2);

// assign a callback
q.drain = function() {
    console.log('all items have been processed');
}

// add some items to the queue
q.push({name: 'foo'}, function (err) {
    console.log('finished processing foo');
});
```

[github.com/caolan/async#queue](https://github.com/caolan/async#queue)

In your particular situation, just wait to call the `callback()` until whatever timing or transaction detail you are waiting for has completed.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how [Promise throttle](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-throttle) works under the hood, I believe `Promise` a better approach compared to `setTimeout`, with promise it is more event based, my issue with that npm package is, it offers no callback option once your call is done, my implemenation would be something like:

```js
class PromiseThrottler {
  constructor(maxParallelCalls) {
      this.maxParallelCalls = maxParallelCalls;
      this.currentCalls = 0; // flag holding the no. of parallel calls at any point
      this.queue = []; // queue maintaining the waiting calls
    }
    // pormiseFn - the fn that wraps some promise call the we need to make, thenChain -  callback once your async call is done, args- arguments that needs to be passed to the function
  add(promiseFn, thenChain, ...args) {
    this.queue.push({
      promiseFn, thenChain, args
    });
    this.call();
  }
  call() {
    if (!this.queue.length || this.currentCalls >= this.maxParallelCalls) return;
    this.currentCalls++;
    let obj = this.queue.shift();
    let chain = obj.args.length ? obj.promiseFn(...obj.args) : obj.promiseFn();
    if (obj.thenChain) chain.then(obj.thenChain);
    chain
      .catch(() => {})
      .then(() => {
        this.currentCalls--;
        this.call();
      });
    this.call();
  }
}

//usage 

let PT = new PromiseThrottler(50)
  , rn = max => Math.floor(Math.random() * max) // generate Random number
  , randomPromise = id => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(id), rn(5000))) // random promise generating function
  , i = 1
  , thenCall = id => {
    console.log('resolved for id:', id);
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    div.textContent = `resolved for id: ${id}`;
    document.body.appendChild(div);
  };

while (++i < 501) PT.add(randomPromise, thenCall, i);
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple way of limiting this is to use `setTimeout` and do a "recursive" loop like this.

```
function asyncLoop() {
  makeAPICall(function(result) {
    writeToDataBase(result, function() {
      setTimeout(asyncLoop, 1000);
    });
  });
}
```

And of course you can also use that same strategy with promises.

Comment: Interesting approach. I have a feeling that Promise throttling libraries and probably doing this type of thing behind the scenes... Are there any downsides to this?

Comment: The only problem with this is that setTimeout has a minimum amount of time it will wait. That amount can be several ms.